# compilation error while uploading sketch to arduino uno

Tags: arduino-uno

I'm stuck in uploading the arduino sketch to the uno board. I ran into a type error problem. I am not using the polulu wheel encoder. Please help me resolve this issue.

```
RobotController:14: error: 'PololuWheelEncoders2' does not name a type
RobotController.pde: In function 'void setup()':
RobotController:83: error: 'encoders' was not declared in this scope
RobotController.pde: In function 'void ReadSonar()':
RobotController:271: error: 'MID_SPEED' was not declared in this scope
RobotController.pde: In function 'int NormalizeSpeed(int)':
RobotController:340: error: 'MID_SPEED' was not declared in this scope
RobotController:343: error: 'MID_SPEED' was not declared in this scope
RobotController.pde: In function 'void SetMotors(int, int, int, int, bool, bool, bool)':
RobotController:359: error: 'encoders' was not declared in this scope
RobotController.pde: In function 'void NormalizeMotors()':
RobotController:368: error: 'MID_SPEED' was not declared in this scope
RobotController:369: error: 'encoders' was not declared in this scope
RobotController.pde: In function 'void SynchronizeMotors()':
RobotController:392: error: 'encoders' was not declared in this scope
RobotController:398: error: 'MID_SPEED' was not declared in this scope
RobotController:407: error: 'MID_SPEED' was not declared in this scope
```

---

```
#include <Usb.h>
#include <AndroidAccessory.h>
#include <PololuWheelEncoders2.h>
#include <Servo.h>

AndroidAccessory acc("Manufacturer", "Model", "Description", "Version", "URI", "Serial");
byte RcvMsg[5];
byte SntMsg[5];

Servo rightSideMotors;
Servo leftSideMotors;
PololuWheelEncoders2 encoders;
const int MIN_SPEED = 40;

const int MAX_SPEED = 140;
const int RIGHT_ADV_THRES = 100;

const int WHEEL_CIR = 36;  //wheel circumference in cm
const int BAUD_RATE = 9600;

const int LAS_HOR_PIN = 2; //blue
const int LAS_VERT_PIN = 3; //white
const int CAM_HOR_PIN = 4;
const int CAM_VERT_PIN = 5;

const int FRONT_SONAR = 8;
const int REAR_SONAR = 9;

const int SPEED_CONT_PIN = 14;
const int DIR_CONT_PIN = 6;

int LoopCount = 0;

Servo LaserHor;
Servo CameraHor;
Servo CameraVert;
Servo LaserVert;

int RightSideAdv = 0;
long LeftSideStop = 0;
long RightSideStop = 0;
int LeftSideSpeed = 0;
int RightSideSpeed = 0;

const int DELAY = 1;
const int READ_SONAR_FREQ = 10;
const int BROADCAST_SONAR_FREQ = 10;
const int SONAR_SAMPLES = 30;
const int SONAR_TAKE_ACTION_THRESHOLD = 50;
const int SYNCH_MOTORS_FREQ = 100;

bool HeedSonar = true;
bool Synchronize = false;
bool WatchForStop = true;

bool TEST_CYCLE = false;
int TEST_COUNT = 0;

enum Commands { CmdMoveForward, CmdMoveForwardDistance, CmdMoveBackward, CmdMoveBackwardDistance, CmdSpinLeft, CmdSpinLeftDistance, CmdSpinRight, CmdSpinRightDistance, CmdStop, CmdMoveCameraVert, CmdMoveCameraHor };
enum Events { EvtFrontSonar, EvtRearSonar, EvtSonarStop, EvtDistanceStop };

void setup () {
Serial.begin(BAUD_RATE);

//LaserHor.attach(LAS_HOR_PIN);
LaserVert.attach(LAS_VERT_PIN);
CameraHor.attach(CAM_HOR_PIN);
CameraVert.attach(CAM_VERT_PIN);

//LaserHor.write(90);
LaserVert.write(90);
CameraHor.write(90);
CameraVert.write(90);

rightSideMotors.attach(SPEED_CONT_PIN);
leftSideMotors.attach(DIR_CONT_PIN);

pinMode(FRONT_SONAR, INPUT);
pinMode(REAR_SONAR, INPUT);

encoders.init(10, 11, 13, 12);

MoveForward(50, 1000);
acc.powerOn();
}

void TestCycle() {
/*Serial.println("STOPPING:");
Serial.println(LeftSideStop);
Serial.println(RightSideStop);
Serial.println(abs(encoders.getCountsLeft()) - LeftSideStop);
Serial.println(abs(encoders.getCountsRight()) - RightSideStop);*/
TEST_COUNT++;
if (TEST_COUNT == 1) {
    CameraHor.write(45);
    delay(150);
    CameraHor.write(0);
    delay(1000);
    CameraHor.write(45);
    delay(150);
    CameraHor.write(135);
    delay(150);
    CameraHor.write(180);
    delay(1000);
    CameraHor.write(135);
    delay(150);
    CameraHor.write(90);
    delay(150);
    SpinRight(50, 180);
}
if (TEST_COUNT == 2) {
    CameraVert.write(45);
    delay(500);
    CameraVert.write(135);
    delay(500);
    CameraVert.write(90);
    delay(500);
    MoveForward(90, 1000);
}
if (TEST_COUNT == 3) {
    CameraVert.write(130);
}
}

void loop() {
if (acc.isConnected()) {
    LaserVert.write(130);
    ReadIncomingSignal();
    if (WatchForStop) {
        NormalizeMotors();
    }
    if (HeedSonar) {
        UpdateLoopCount();
        if (LoopCount % READ_SONAR_FREQ == 0) {
            ReadSonar();
        }

        if (LoopCount % SYNCH_MOTORS_FREQ == 0) {
            SynchronizeMotors();
        }
        delay(DELAY);
    }
}
else {
    LaserVert.write(90);
}
}

void SendToAndroid(byte signal, unsigned long value) {
//Serial.print("Sending: ");
//Serial.println(signal);
SntMsg[0] = signal;
SntMsg[1] = value >> 24;
SntMsg[2] = value >> 16;
SntMsg[3] = value >> 8;
SntMsg[4] = value;

acc.write(SntMsg, 5);
}

void ReadIncomingSignal() {
int len = acc.read(RcvMsg, 9, 1);

while (len > 0) {
    switch(RcvMsg[0]){
        case CmdMoveForward:
            {
                int speed = getIntFromBytes(RcvMsg[1], RcvMsg[2], RcvMsg[3], RcvMsg[4]);
                MoveForward(speed);
                break;
            }
        case CmdMoveForwardDistance:
            {
                int speed = getIntFromBytes(RcvMsg[1], RcvMsg[2], RcvMsg[3], RcvMsg[4]);
                int distance = getIntFromBytes(RcvMsg[5], RcvMsg[6], RcvMsg[7], RcvMsg[8]);
                MoveForward(speed, distance);
                break;
            }
        case CmdMoveBackward:
            {
                int speed = getIntFromBytes(RcvMsg[1], RcvMsg[2], RcvMsg[3], RcvMsg[4]);
                MoveBackward(speed);
                break;
            }
        case CmdMoveBackwardDistance:
            {
                int speed = getIntFromBytes(RcvMsg[1], RcvMsg[2], RcvMsg[3], RcvMsg[4]);
                int distance = getIntFromBytes(RcvMsg[5], RcvMsg[6], RcvMsg[7], RcvMsg[8]);
                MoveBackward(speed, distance);
                break;
            }
        case CmdSpinLeft:
            {
                int speed = getIntFromBytes(RcvMsg[1], RcvMsg[2], RcvMsg[3], RcvMsg[4]);
                SpinLeft(speed);
                break;
            }
        case CmdSpinLeftDistance:
            {
                int speed = getIntFromBytes(RcvMsg[1], RcvMsg[2], RcvMsg[3], RcvMsg[4]);
                int distance = getIntFromBytes(RcvMsg[5], RcvMsg[6], RcvMsg[7], RcvMsg[8]);
                SpinLeft(speed, distance);
                break;
            }
        case CmdSpinRight:
            {
                int speed = getIntFromBytes(RcvMsg[1], RcvMsg[2], RcvMsg[3], RcvMsg[4]);
                SpinRight(speed);
                break;
            }
        case CmdSpinRightDistance:
            {
                int speed = getIntFromBytes(RcvMsg[1], RcvMsg[2], RcvMsg[3], RcvMsg[4]);
                int distance = getIntFromBytes(RcvMsg[5], RcvMsg[6], RcvMsg[7], RcvMsg[8]);
                SpinRight(speed, distance);
                break;
            }
        case CmdStop:
            {
                Stop();
                break;
            }
        case CmdMoveCameraVert:
            {
                int degrees = getIntFromBytes(RcvMsg[1], RcvMsg[2], RcvMsg[3], RcvMsg[4]);
                MoveCameraVert(degrees);
                break;
            }
        case CmdMoveCameraHor:
            {
                int degrees = getIntFromBytes(RcvMsg[1], RcvMsg[2], RcvMsg[3], RcvMsg[4]);
                MoveCameraHor(degrees);
                break;
            }
    }
    len = acc.read(RcvMsg, 9, 1);
}
}

int getIntFromBytes(byte b1, byte b2, byte b3, byte b4)
{
int value = 0;
value += b1;
value <<= 8;
value += b2;
value <<= 8;
value += b3;
value <<= 8;
value += b4;
return value;
}

void UpdateLoopCount() {
LoopCount = (LoopCount % 1000) + 1;
   }

void ReadSonar() 
{
unsigned long frontSum = 0;
unsigned long rearSum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < SONAR_SAMPLES; i++) {
    unsigned long frontDuration = pulseIn(FRONT_SONAR, HIGH);
    unsigned long rearDuration = pulseIn(REAR_SONAR, HIGH);
    frontSum += frontDuration / 147.0 * 2.54;
    rearSum += rearDuration / 147.0 * 2.54;
    }

    unsigned long frontAvg = frontSum / SONAR_SAMPLES;
unsigned long rearAvg = rearSum / SONAR_SAMPLES;
bool forward = LeftSideSpeed > MID_SPEED || RightSideSpeed > MID_SPEED;

if (HeedSonar && ((forward && frontAvg <= SONAR_TAKE_ACTION_THRESHOLD) || (!forward && rearAvg <= SONAR_TAKE_ACTION_THRESHOLD))) {
    Stop();
}

Serial.println(LoopCount);
Serial.println(frontAvg);
if (LoopCount % BROADCAST_SONAR_FREQ == 0) {
    SendToAndroid(EvtFrontSonar, frontAvg);
    SendToAndroid(EvtRearSonar, rearAvg);
}
}

void MoveForward(int speed) {
SetMotors(speed, speed, 0, 0, true, true, false);
}

void MoveForward(int speed, int cms) {
SetMotors(speed, speed, cms, cms, true, true, true);
}

void MoveBackward(int speed) {
SetMotors(-speed, -speed, 0, 0, true, true, false);
}

void MoveBackward(int speed, int cms) {
SetMotors(-speed, -speed, cms, cms, true, true, true);
}

void SpinLeft(int speed) {
SetMotors(-speed, speed, 0, 0, true, false, false);
}

void SpinLeft(int speed, int degrees) {
int cms = (degrees / 3.0);
int extra = ((cms - 30) / 30.0);
cms += extra;
SetMotors(-speed, speed, cms, cms, true, false, true);
}

void SpinRight(int speed) {
SetMotors(speed, -speed, 0, 0, true, false, false);
}

void SpinRight(int speed, int degrees) {
int cms = (degrees / 3.0);
int extra = ((cms - 30) / 30.0) * 2.0;
cms += extra;
SetMotors(speed, -speed, cms, cms, true, false, true);
}

void MoveCameraVert(int degrees) {
CameraVert.write(degrees);
}

void MoveCameraHor(int degrees) {
CameraHor.write(degrees);
}

void Stop() {
SetMotors(0, 0, 0, 0, false, true, true);
if (TEST_CYCLE) {
    TestCycle();
}
}

int NormalizeSpeed(int speedAsPercent) {
if (speedAsPercent == 0) {
    return MID_SPEED;
}
else {
    return (int)(MID_SPEED + ((MAX_SPEED - MID_SPEED) * (speedAsPercent / 100.0)));
}
}

long NormalizeDistance(int cms) {
return (long)((cms * 3200.0) / WHEEL_CIR); //64 counts per rev, 50:1 ratio = 64 * 50 = 3200
}

void SetMotors(int leftSpeed, int rightSpeed, int leftStop, int rightStop, bool synchronize, bool heedSonar, bool watchForStop) {
LeftSideSpeed = NormalizeSpeed(leftSpeed);
RightSideSpeed = NormalizeSpeed(rightSpeed);
LeftSideStop = NormalizeDistance(leftStop);
RightSideStop = NormalizeDistance(rightStop);
leftSideMotors.write(LeftSideSpeed);
rightSideMotors.write(RightSideSpeed);

encoders.getCountsAndResetRight();
encoders.getCountsAndResetLeft();
Synchronize = synchronize;
HeedSonar = heedSonar;
WatchForStop = watchForStop;
RightSideAdv = 0;
  }

void NormalizeMotors() {
if (LeftSideSpeed != MID_SPEED || RightSideSpeed != MID_SPEED) {
    long left = abs(encoders.getCountsLeft());
    long right = abs(encoders.getCountsRight());
    bool stopLeft = left >= LeftSideStop;
    bool stopRight = right >= RightSideStop;

    if (stopLeft && stopRight) {
        Stop();
    }
    else {
        if (stopLeft) {
            LeftSideSpeed = 0;
            leftSideMotors.write(MID_SPEED);
        }
        if (stopRight) {
            RightSideSpeed = 0;
            rightSideMotors.write(MID_SPEED);
        }
    }
}
}

void SynchronizeMotors() {
if (Synchronize) {
    long left = abs(encoders.getCountsLeft());
    long right = abs(encoders.getCountsRight());
    int newRightAdv = right - left;
    if (abs(newRightAdv) > RIGHT_ADV_THRES && abs(newRightAdv) > abs(RightSideAdv)) {
        if (newRightAdv > 0) {
            //Serial.println("DOWN");
            if (RightSideSpeed < MID_SPEED) {
                RightSideSpeed += 1;
            }
            else {
                RightSideSpeed -= 1;
            }
        }
        else {
            //Serial.println("UP");
            if (RightSideSpeed < MID_SPEED) {
                RightSideSpeed -= 1;
            }
            else {
                RightSideSpeed += 1;
            }
        }
        rightSideMotors.write(RightSideSpeed);
    }
    RightSideAdv = newRightAdv;
}
}
```

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Do you not need the Poloulu wheel encoders? In line 12, you create a variable named "encoders" which is set to type = PololuWheelEncoders2. The error is telling you that this is not a valid type for a variable.